# Boostrap fix size of the columns in function of the first column

Tags: css, svg, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a row with two columns:

- the first columns contains a svg with a size in viewbox and col-md-8
- the second columns contains a text with variable size

I want all columns in the same size ( the size of the first columns define by the svg) if the contains of the second size is too long i want use a scroll of this columns

I already try with flex but it's the biggest columns who decide the size any other solution

ps: the width is not the problems, i search to fix the height of the second div in function of the height of the first without use a style='height:xx%' or px

code :

```css
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;
```

```html
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1500 500"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="overflow-y:scroll">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please show the code that you have written to achieve it? what you've tried and what didn't work

Comment: Cant you just use: `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div></div>`?

Comment: No the width is not the problems, i search to fix the height of the second div in function of the height of the first

Comment: do you wish to use a simple JavaScript? i think we will need to write js to achieve it

Comment: if possible , i prefere don't use js

Comment: well, i guess it's not possible to get the height of the element without using js, so i prefer using it. i have answered it below, please take a look and comment if there is still a problem

Answer (score 0):

i have created a Fiddle using bootstrap here https://jsfiddle.net/jn9cwngs/3/

here you can see, i have removed all your CSS and changed your HTML a little bit like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
```

you can use `col-*` as you wish.

and i have used a simple js to define height of content as the svg

```
jQuery(function(){
  var images = $('svg');
  var height;
  images.each(function(){
    var image = $(this);
    height = image.height();
  });
  var content = $('.description');
  content.each(function(){
    var text = $(this);
    text.height(height);
  });
});
```